# Twenty Eleven Theme Adjusts for iPhones. How to stop this feature?

Tags: theme-twenty-eleven, mobile, responsive

I would like to prevent Twenty Eleven from changing to mobile version when seen on an iPhone.  Any way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove everything following the line

```
/* =Responsive Structure
----------------------------------------------- */
```

up until in the style.css for Twenty Eleven

```
/* =Print
----------------------------------------------- */
```

and it will get rid of all the media queries which are based on the size of the page.

Comment: Just to make it clear he's talking on the theme style.css file.

Comment: Didn't seem to work until I removed the viewport meta tag in header.php.  But still doesn't style correctly.  Any ideas?

Comment: How do you mean by doesn't style correctly?